# Button renders as simple text when add programmatically inside table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add dynamically row to table ( last td cell contains button  )

In firefox when I look generated row with firebug I get like

```
<td class="center_vertical">
    <a class="custom-button" data-name="63" name="drag_req" data-role="button"></a>
</td>
```

but it is not rendered as button, just like simple text ( not clickable, no bordred around).
I create row in js like

```
        var rowContent = '<tr valign="middle"><td class="center_vertical"><a data-role="button" class="custom-button" name="drag_req" data-name="'+ responseData['id'] + '">Drag</a></td></tr>';
        $('#my_data_requests > tbody:last').html(rowContent);
```

( responseData is dictionary with all used keys )
When I create same html in template it renders Drag like button not simple text.
Does anyone have idea what is wrong ?

Comment: which jQM version are you using? and are you using _table_ widget?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of the single quotes in `responseData['id']`? They might be messing up the string. I would declare the var separately so that there are no single quotes in the rowContent string.

```
var responseData_id = responseData['id'];
var rowContent = '<tr valign="middle"><td class="center_vertical"><a data-role="button" class="custom-button" name="drag_req" data-name="'+ responseData_id + '">Drag</a></td></tr>';
$('#my_data_requests > tbody:last').html(rowContent);
```

Comment: I have changed but it is still the same ( I also tried append instead of html but same)